# What is the largest single burn plane change maneuver executed in LEO?

Tags: orbital-maneuver, delta-v, record

Below 2000 km in low Earth orbit (or close to it), what is the largest propulsive plane change from a single burn?

Expecting an answer in degrees, a named mission and vehicle executing the burn itself.

Now what does "or close to it" mean?

- includes 2nd stage burns before full orbital velocity has been achieved
- excludes low altitude doglegs executed by first stages